# Is it possible to open devtools on the network tab?

Tags: chromium-embedded, dyalog

I am developing an application in Dyalog APL using its HtmlRenderer object (which is based on the Chromium Embedded Framework). There is a facility to open DevTools - but is it possible to have DevTools initially open the Network tab so that I could analyze the loading of the first URL?

I found `--devtools-flags` but I'm unsure if that could answer the question and what I'd have to pass?

**Update**:
I was able to (partially) solve it in APL with a ⎕DL 2 after ⎕WCing the HtmlRenderer (and calling the ShowDevTools method) and setting the HTML property afterwards. Doesn't show the Network tab immediately, but records the pageload.

Would still be interested to learn about --devtools-flags though...

*(I first posted this as an answer because it was good enough to address my urgent problem - but like one comment suggested, it doesn't answer the question)*